# VBA Type mismatch error when setting Excel Range in Word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have the following code as part of my sub trying to assign a range:

```
'Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim xlApp As Object
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = False
xlApp.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim CRsFile As String
Dim CRsMaxRow As Integer

' get the CR list
CRsFile = "CRs.xls"
Set CRsWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Docs\" + CRsFile)
With CRsWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  .Activate
  CRsMaxRow = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

  Set CRs = .Range("A2:M" & CRsMaxRow)

End With

Dim interestingFiles As Range

' get the files names that we consider interesting to track
Set FilesWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("files.xlsx")
With FilesWB.Worksheets("files")
    .Activate
    Set interestingFiles = .Range("A2:E5")
End With
```

Do you have any idea why am I getting a run time type mismatch error?

Answer (score 2):

If you run the code from Word then the problem is in the declaration of 'interestingFiles' variable. **Range exist in Word as well** so use either Variant or add reference to Excel and then use Excel.Range.

Without Excel reference:

```
Dim interestingFiles As Variant
```

And with Excel reference:

```
Dim interestingFiles As Excel.Range
```

Comment: Ahhh this might be getting to the root of the problem. OP didn't say what Application is running this subroutine, but that would make sense.

Comment: Confirmed this will fix the problem in Word :) Good job!

Answer (score 0):

Kindly set xlApp object as in below code. 
Also you provide complete path for your workbook when opening it.

```
Sub test()
        Dim interestingFiles As Range
        Dim xlApp As Object

        Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
        ' get the files names

        Dim path As String
        path = "C:\Users\Santosh\Desktop\file1.xlsx"

        Set FilesWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path)
        With FilesWB.Worksheets(1)
            .Activate
            Set interestingFiles = .Range("A2:E5")
        End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: Without setting the `xlApp` I'd expect a `424 Object required` error, or if the file doesn't exist, there'd be an error at `Set FilesWB =...`, but OP indicates a `mismatch` error "setting the range". I don't see anything inside that `With` block that looks incorrect.

Comment: @DavidZemens Do you think its `xlApp.Workbooks.Open("files.xlsx")` an issue ?

Comment: in m code I put the full path - I did not feel comfortable reviling it on the web...

Comment: @santosh perhaps, but that isn't going to cause a mismatch. Try it yourself, You should get `424 Object Required` if `xlApp` isn't set, and a `1004` otherwise. Still not able to replicate a mismatch error at any point in this code.

Comment: @DavidZemens if you read my answer i just pointed out where the code might go wrong. Thanks for additional info.

Comment: I have updates the xlapp part and edited the question to include all the code (minus full path). I actually open another workbook before the problematic one - may be this is the root for the problem?

Comment: just wanted to add that what I first had was: Set xlApp = CreatObject("Excel.Application"). and this is why I did not get the 424 error.

Comment: @Santosh I see you mentioned the necessary full path -- without the full path, `Set FilesWB` raises a `1004` error, not a `mismatch` error.  I'm trying to replicate the error as reported by OP, and so far I am not able to do so. Can you replicate a `mismatch` error???

Comment: to add more info - I run the code from the word VBA editor - does it make a difference?

Comment: @banjo yes that will make a difference, since `Range` is an object in Word, as well. See Daniel's answer for the fix!